# Goldbach's conjecture proof based on a continuous approach and on a discrete approach

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, goldbachs-conjecture

I conducted a study on the Goldbach binary conjecture and now I will show my proposal to demonstrate this conjecture, where P{2} represents the odd prime numbers set. I would like to know if you think this demonstration is correct, thank you very much.

So I will formulate the conjecture in mathematical terms not considering the number 4, since this natural number is the only writable as the sum of 2 even prime numbers.

Strong Goldbach conjecture statement:

```
               ∀ k ∈ N*\{1,2} ∃ p,q ∈ P\{2} | 2k = p + q
```

Proof

```
               ∀ k’∈ N*|k’< k → k’ = k - k°      k° < k, k° ∈ N*

               2k’ = 2(k - k°) = 2k - 2k°
```

An even number can be written as a sum of two odd numbers hence:

```
               2k’ = (2k” + 1) + (2k’’’ + 1)         k”, k’’’ ∈ N*
```

We know that every odd number can be written as a difference between a prime and an even number, therefore:

```
               2k” + 1 = p – 2k^IV

               2k”’ + 1 = q – 2k^V                   k^IV, k^V ∈ N,  p, q ∈ P\{2}

               2k’ = (p – 2k^IV) + (q – 2k^V)   

               2k’ = p + q – 2(k^IV + 2k^V)   

               2k’ = p + q – 2k^VI                   k^VI ∈ N*          

              *2k - 2k° = p + q – 2k^VI

               p, q ∈ 2Z+1 → 2n = p + q              n ∈ N*\{1,2}    

               2k - 2k° = 2n – 2k^VI 

             ** k - k° = n – k^VI
```

Continuous approach. We can express a real number as a function of every other real number, hence (given that N ⊂ R):

```
               k - k° = n – k^VI       n = f(k) 

               k - k° = f(k) – k^VI    f(k) = g*k,  g ∈ R|g*k ∈ N*\{1,2}        

               k - k° = g*k – k^VI                  g ∈ G, G ⊂ R

               2n = 2f(k) = 2g*k → 2g*k = p + q   

               2k = p*g^-1 + q*g^-1 = (p + q)*g^-1  

               lim(g → 1)⁡2k = p + q
```

Otherwise we can say that g = 1 guarantees that (p + q) is an integer greater than 4 while the fact that both p and q are odd numbers guarantees that the parity of (p + q) is in agreement with 2k parity.

Discrete approach. We can also say:

```
  *2k = p + q – 2(k^VI - k°) where if k° = k^VI ⇒ 2k = p + q, k ∈ N*\{1,2}, p, q ∈ P\{2}
```

or

```
       **n = k ± k°’,  k°’∈ N hence 2n = 2(k ± k°’) = p + q where k°’ = 0 ⇒ 2k = p + q
```

Comment: Why is this proof written with so many symbols? Proofs are about ideas, which are best expressed in English (or some other natural language). Can you distill the basic *idea* of your proposed proof into simple sentences?

Comment: This is very hard to follow.  You appear to be trying to give an explicit construction.  That is, given $2k$ you appear to construct primes $p,q$ with $p+q=2k$.  But do you?  If $2k=24=15+9$ we write $15=17-2,9=11-2$.  Then $p=17, q=11$.  Yes?  But $17+11\neq 24$.  So what are you saying?  If I have misunderstood your construction (high probability) then please go through an explicit numerical example in your post.

Comment: In your example  2k = 24, k = 12;  so we have to find p and q such that 2k =24 = p + q
We take, for example, K’ = k -2 =10  and so  2k’ = 10*2 = 20
20 = 24 – 4,   20 = 11 + 9
24 – 4 = 11 + 9 = (13 – 2)  + (11 -2) = (13 + 11) – (2  + 2) --> 24 – 4 = (13 + 11) – 4 
from which it derives that 24 = 13 + 11
But I think the heart of the demonstration is when we arrive to say that
k - k ° = f (k) - k ^ VI from which derives this important statement : 2n = 2f(k) = 2g * k → 2g * k = p + q

Comment: @DanieleBertaggia How did it so conveniently happen that, when you chose $k'=k-2$, and then chose $20=11+9$ - both $11+2$ and $9+2$ turned out to be prime? (I know, some other pairs would do in your proof, but isn't finding such pairs actually *equivalent* to Goldbach's conjecture?)

Comment: As I said above, I humbly think that we must arm ourselves with patience and follow the demonstration from the beginning to the end. My approach is of the arithmetic-algebraic type and examples that confirm the passage in question are always possible. But I repeat, in my opinion, the proof must be analyzed from the beginning to the end from a logical-set point of view. I would like to understand in which single algebraic-arithmetic step I'm doing wrong ...

Answer (score 2):

I did not have time to look at your continuous proof, but the discrete one has a flaw. Your $p$ and $q$ *depend on the choice of $k^0$* but then later you forget about that and just set $k^0$ to be equal to $k^{VI}$.

Comment: And that is quite an elementary flaw: making the same flaw, you can conclude that every number is $0$: start with $a\in\mathbb R$, split it as a sum $a=b+c$ and then let's choose $c$ to be $-b$ so $a=b+(-b)=0$.

Comment: In your example, it seems to me that there is an initial defect, you want to prove a untruth: to show that all the numbers are 0 (which finds countless counterexample that deny it, rather exist only a circumstance that confirm it: c=-b ). On the contrary, I try to prove a conjecture that at the moment does not yet present a counterexample that denies it. For do this I rely on the Euclid's theorem on the infinity of prime numbers, which allows me to always identify a prime number greater than an odd number...

Comment: @DanieleBertaggia, I think you should reply to the comments directly below your question, in particluar, to the one by lulu.

Comment: @DanieleBertaggia My point is that, with flawed reasoning as in your proof, you *can* purportedly prove untruths. Similarly, Goldbach's conjecture may still be false and you may still think that you've proven it. Please have a look at my answer and try to understand the reason your 'discrete proof' is flawed.